# How to turn off sourceMap in ui5-cli?

Tags: ui5-tooling

Is it possible to turn-off sourceMap in ui5-cli?
I'm trying with many configurations but still failing.

```
  bundles:
    - bundleDefinition:
        name: "No sourceMap"
        defaultFileTypes:
          - .js
      bundleOptions:
        sourceMap: false
```

This is one of my last try but not working.
I want to remove this because my SAP S4 system have problem with uploading .map files.